# When throwing an ArgumentException with an @Escaped identifier, what should I use as the paramName?

Tags: c#, argumentexception

When throwing an ArgumentException with an @Escaped identifier (EG `@this`), what should I use as the paramName?  Would I use `this` or `@this`?

As an example, suppose I have an extension method for an enum `SomeEnum`.  I want to throw an [`InvalidEnumArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) when an invalid enum is here.

```c#
public static string GetCode(this SomeEnum @this) {
    switch (@this) {
    case SomeEnum.Foo: return "Foo";
    case SomeEnum.Bar: return "Bar";
    case SomeEnum.Baz: return "Baz";
    //This is what I'm not sure of                   vvvvv
    default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("@this", (int)@this, typeof(SomeEnum));
    }
}
```

Is the above the correct way?  Or should I do this:

```c#
default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("this", (int)@this, typeof(SomeEnum));
```

Given that different languages have different syntaxes for this (VB uses `[this]`, from what I know), I would assume that the second option is correct, but I would like to verify this.

---

EDIT: To clarify, since most people seem not to know: When a identifier is prefaced with `@`, it is forced to be treated as an identifier rather than a keyword, but `@something` and `something` are still the same identifier.  [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx).  Of course, that doesn't apply when doing `@this`, as `this` isn't a valid identifier.

Comment: If you need to escape the name of a parameter you might want to think about naming it something else.

Comment: I think, the best decision would be to match `nameof(@this)` behavior of upcoming C# 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual name of the parameter (horrid as it is) is `"this"`.  That's what you'll see in the metadata.  The `@` is just required so that the compiler knows that you actually used a reserved word *on purpose*.

Answer (score -1):

it's typically a much better solution to avoid using a keyword in the first place:

```
public static string GetCode(this SomeEnum aSomeEnum)
{
    switch (aSomeEnum)
    {
        case SomeEnum.Foo: return "Foo";
        case SomeEnum.Bar: return "Bar";
        case SomeEnum.Baz: return "Baz";
        default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("aSomeEnum", (int)aSomeEnum, typeof(SomeEnum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, "this" is a bad choice for a name of a parameter -- it causes unnecessary confusion. Pick just about anything else (I'd go for `someEnum`). If you *do* name the parameter "this", then you should use that in the constructor, as that is its name. How you have to escape that name to make C# accept it isn't relevant to its runtime name, which is what the exception should concern itself with if you want to be a good, language-agnostic .NET citizen. (However, it's a bad choice for a name precisely *because* `this` is so familiar to C# programmers.)